# How can i append values to an existing key in a dictionary in python? in a loop without " "

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
names=['john', 'paul', 'george']
newdict={}

rango=input('enter a number ')

for numbers in range(0, int(rango)):

for i in names:
    newdict[i]=[]
    num = input('enter a number for the ' + str(i) + ' ')
    newdict[i].append(num)

print(newdict)
```

**I insert this numbers**

```
 enter a number 2
 enter a number for the john 2
 enter a number for the paul 3
 enter a number for the george 4
 enter a number for the john 5
 enter a number for the paul 6
 enter a number for the George 7
```

**The output is the following**

```
{'john': ['5'], 'paul': ['6'], 'george': ['7']}
```

**but I want the following output:**

```
{'john': [2, 5], 'paul': [3, 6], 'george': [4, 7]}
```

How can I get this output? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: On every iteration, you set the key to an empty list, *and then* you append. Don't do that: `newdict[i]=[]`

Comment: if I erase that part, python give me a error:                                                                      newdict[i].append(num)
KeyError: 'john'

Comment: Right, because that key doesn't exist...

Comment: and how can I make the program work like I want?

Answer (score 5):

Don't do `newdict[i]=[]` instead check the value of the names already present or not, If not present then append it.

```
names=['john', 'paul', 'george']
newdict={}
rango=input('enter a number\n')
for numbers in range(0, int(rango)):
    for i in names:
        num = input('enter a number for the ' + str(i) + ' \n')
        if i in newdict:
            newdict[i].append(num)
        else:
            newdict[i] =[num]
print(newdict)
```

Output:

```
{'john': ['2', '5'], 'paul': ['3', '6'], 'george': ['4', '7']}
```

Comment: there's is a form of making without the ' ' ? like this {'john': [2,'5], 'paul': [3, '], 'george': [4, 7]}

Comment: @searchandprint, I don't understand, please clarify your statement

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this way:

```
names = ['john', 'paul', 'george']
newdict = {}
rango=input('enter a number\n')

for numbers in range(0, int(rango)):
    for name in names:
        if name not in newdict:
            newdict[name] = []

        num = input('enter a number for the ' + str(name) + ' ')
        newdict[name].append(num)

print(newdict)
```

Create new array only if the key is not present already.

But if is already there then you just append the new value :)